# Can't open Sync window in Firefox

Tags: firefox, sync

1. I open Firefox.
2. I open the Tools menu.
3. I click on the button "Sync".
4. And **nothing** happens. Nothing opens.

How can I open Sync?

I use Firefox v29.0.

Comment: what happens if you start firefox from the terminal and clicks on sync, do you get any errors in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes sync in firefox get activated without any user setup probably a bug. If you want to deactivate the active account and add your account. go to menu bar > edit > preferences > sync and click deactivate account.

[image]

If you want to open your sync account and view your bookmarks and settings then there is no way in firefox. In Firefox sync you cant view your sync data(stuff). Its better to use xmarks-sync addon compatible with firefox and chrome.

To install xmarks add-on
go to tools => add-ons and get addons search for xmarks

Comment: I just want to **turn on** Sync.

Comment: Did you created a firefox account using set up sync

Comment: Yes, but on another computer. Here I just want to log in.

Comment: then at tool you will get set up sync option

Comment: There's no option like that.

Comment: if you can find just sync and not set up sync then someone has already created a sync account

Comment: How can I download `xmarks-sync` addon?

Comment: go to tools => add-ons and get addons search for xmarks

Comment: it will be xmarks 4.2.1 like that

Comment: And how can I delete that account from the browser?

Comment: you need know the account details https://account.services.mozilla.com/ and can delete from here

Comment: try going to edit > preferences > sync there you may find stop sync

Comment: Pls post it as an answer.

Comment: Did that work from the preferences

Comment: Yes, previously I set up Sync but I didn't remember!